# Оригинал и оригинальность

Tags: значение-слов

Слова оригинал и оригинальность - это одно и то же?

Comment: Пишутся не одинаково, значит уже не одно и то же. Сформулируйте иначе Ваш вопрос, иначе проблема не ясна.

Answer (score 3):

Это однокоренные существительные, но оригинал – это предмет, человек, а  оригинальность – это качество, свойство (отвлеченное существительное).

Например: Оригинал – это человек, отличающийся оригинальностью. Эта рукопись – оригинал, специалисты подтверждают ее оригинальность (подлинность).

Из словаря:

**ОРИГИНАЛ,** -[от лат. originalis – первоначальный] 1. То, что или тот, кто послужил предметом воспроизведения, копирования и т.п.; подлинник. О. утрачен. О. картины. 2. Разг. Странный, непохожий на других человек; чудак. Считаться, казаться, выглядеть оригиналом.

**ОРИГИНАЛЬНЫЙ,**  [от лат. originalis - первоначальный] 1. Подлинный, первоначальный. 2. Созданный в результате самостоятельного творчества,  О-ое произведение.  3. Непохожий на других, чуждый подражательности; О. мыслитель.  4. Своеобразный, необычный. О. взгляд на что-л.  **Оригинальность,**  ж. Подтвердить о. рукописи, текста. Отличаться оригинальностью. О. замысла. О. костюма.